# When using sys.stdin.read(), why I am not able to input from keyboard?

Tags: python, input, stdin

My code is as follows:

```
def function(a, b):
    while a != 0 and b != 0:
      ...

    return x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    a, b = map(int, input.split())
    print(function(a, b))
```

When I try to run it, the program doesn't give me a chance to input.

I get the following traceback message:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

[image]

Can someone tell me the reason and how I can make input to test my program.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you aren't using `input`??

Comment: How did you run your program?

Comment: I have to upload it to an online grader so I need to keep the input method intact. The program runs fine in the grader and yield results. I just want to test it locally with my own input.

Comment: What do you mean "I need to keep the `input` method intact"??? `input` is a built-in function, that does what you need it to do. I'm not talking about your variable, `input`, which is *shadowing the built-in function*. Why in the world are you using `sys.stdin`? Anyway, `sys.stdin.read` keeps reading from `stdin` until it encounters an EOF. What system are you on? What exactly are you doing when you run this?

Comment: @anthony sottile I used the Anaconda Spyder and its IPython console. I also run it using macterminal. Both yield the same traceback

Comment: You never get a chance to provide an input? It just errors out immediately? I'm on a Mac, and I can get this to work. It's needlessly annoying because you have to press enter *and then* ctrl-D, which is why you *should be using the `input` function*, but it works.

Comment: you can use sys.argv too

Comment: I mean I need to keep the `sys.stdin.read()` part intact because that's how the online grader input the data. I run it on both mac and window, the result are the same. I was trying to input my own `a` and `b` value to test the program. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: ... How does the online grader *enforce* you to *only* use `sys.stdin.read`??? Does it actually look for you calling that function?! You realize, the `input` function *already reads from standard in*

Comment: Yeah, it just error out immediately. I also run it on mac. The same happens. Being trying for the whole morning to figure out why this happen. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Try it with the `input` function. Also, how exactly are you running this in the terminal? I am currently getting this to work just fine...

Comment: I use the textwrangle to write the program and... just click run. I tried `input` just now, it did not work. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @ZiqianPei um, OK, I don't know anything about textwrangle, but try running this in the terminal `python gcd.py`, which I thought you said you did. But if `input` isn't working, that means *something* is constantly feeding an EOF to stdin without you being able to input anything first.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah. It works using `python3 gcd.py` with both `input` and `stdin.read()`. Thanks!

Comment: But I am still confused why it won't work by using textwrangler or IPython, what could possibly give the input EOF?

Comment: @ZiqianPei I doubt it's IPython. I use it all the time, and have never encountered this behavior. As for Spyder and textwrangler, I could only speculate.

Comment: I did some search and find that maybe it is because IDE like Textwrangler and Spyder run the file as a whole and do not allow command line input. Anyway, thanks a lot! @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Impossible to answer because you provide inaccurate information. If you ran your program from interactive console as you're saying, you would never able to get past `sys.stdin.read()` at all.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.stdin.read()` will read `stdin` until it hits EOF. Normally, this happens when that stream is closed by the other end (i.e. by whatever provides input).

This works if you run your program like `cat inputfile.txt | your_program`. But it will just keep reading endlessly in interactive mode when `stdin` is connected to your terminal, so the only way to close it from the other end is to close the terminal.

Strictly speaking, you can make `read()` stop by inputting a EOF character on a line by itself which is `Ctrl-D` in Unix and `Ctrl-Z` in Windows -- and this works in a regular Python console. But in IPython, this technique doesn't work: here in Windows, I see `Ctrl-D` as `\x04` and `Ctrl-Z` as a blank line and neither stops the read (whether this is a bug or by design is another question).

So,

- Use [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) instead to input a single line, or
- if you require multiple lines of input, use something that puts a limit on how much is read from `stdin`:

  ```
  ll=[]        
  while True:
      l = input()    # or sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
      if not l: break
      ll.append(l)
  ```

  This way, you're able to stop the program from asking for more input by entering a blank line.
- finally, there's [`sys.stdin.isatty()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isatty#file.isatty) which allows you do invoke different code depending on whether the input is interactive (but for your task, this is probably an overkill).

Comment: Um, this isn't true. You can use `sys.stdin.read()`, which will read until an EOF. You can give it an EOF, on OSX for example, by pressing enter then cltr-d. I think most Linux/Unix flavors will interpret just a CTRL-d as EOF.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was getting to that. Yes, you can, but not in IPython.

Comment: I've been testing this in Ipython shells the entire time.

Comment: The Windows console has no pre-determined control character to end a cooked read normally (i.e. not Ctrl+C). For `ReadFile`, the ConDrv device hacks this feature in to return 0 bytes read if a line starts with Ctrl+Z (0x1A). But that's not a function of the console itself, and any program that calls `ReadConsole` or low-level `ReadConsoleInput` has to manually implement this behavior. This was implemented for the new console I/O in Python 3.6, but maybe in the future it can use the `pInputControl` parameter of `ReadConsole` to have the console itself handle this for both Ctrl+Z and Ctrl+D.